# How to parse 後継者としての責務も卒業するまで代理を立てられた

Tags: grammar

> 私が遠野の屋敷に帰ってきていた理由は、一重に父がうるさかったからだ。
> **その父も亡くなり、父の後継者としての責務も卒業するまで代理を立てられた今、私が好き好んでこの屋敷に帰ってくる理由はない**。なにしろ卒業してしまえば、あとはずっとこの屋敷で過ごすのだ。
>
> The reason why I came back to Tohno's mansion is only one, my father was very annoying about it.
> Since my father is no more and so are my duties as the successor, until I graduate the me which has been elected as the proxy,  will do as I please since I have no reason to come back to this mansion.
> At any rate after I graduate, I will always stay here.

Is it correct or am I wrong?

The fan translation is:

> The only reason I came back to the mansion was because my father wanted me to.
> Now that father is dead and I do not have the responsibility as the successor until I graduate, there is no reason for me to come back to this mansion.
> Because when I graduate, I will live in this mansion for the rest of my life.

I am not sure about this passage:

> その父も亡くなり、父の後継者としての責務も卒業するまで代理を立てられた今、私が好き好んでこの屋敷に帰ってくる理由はない。

亡くなり refers to the father and I believe it also refer to the duties as the heir.
With 卒業 starts another different sentence.
That's how I understand it.

So I would say

> その父も亡くなり、父の後継者としての責務も亡くなり, 卒業するまで代理を立てられた今、私が好き好んでこの屋敷に帰ってくる理由はない。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 父の後継者としての責務も卒業するまで代理を立てられた

It might be clearer if you rewrote/parsed it as:

> 卒業するまで、父の後継者としての責務にも代理を立てられた /
>   父の後継者としての責務も、（卒業するまで）代理を立てられた

Which is literally like "Someone has been nominated to perform the duties as my father's successor (in my place) until I graduate."

Hence the translation "I do not have the responsibility as the successor until I graduate."

Comment: 父の後継者としての責務も卒業するまで代理を立てられた

Shouldn't it be 

父の後継者としての責務も卒業するまで の 代理を立てられた

Also how do you understand from that sentence that someone else was elected as a successor?

Comment: Also is 立てられた potential or passive here?

If it's passive why?

Comment: 「父の後継者としての責務も卒業するまで**の**代理を立てられた」 looks fine, too. 代理を立てられた is (indirect) passive, "代理 was nominated", which you can read as "Someone was nominated as a 代理 (for me)"

Comment: Is the indirect passive like the passive of damage?

I mean something like.

僕は穴子にてがみを読まれた

or is it different?

Why is を used here?

Comment: Yes! It has the same construct as the suffering passive. 代理が立てられた would just be "a 代理 was nominated", and (私は)代理を立てられた would imply that it might influence 私 in some way.

Comment: So the indirect passive can have the topic and the direct object with を without an agent に?

That would only mean that the Topic did an action on something which affected him?

For example something like

僕は手紙を読まれた

Could it imply that I read it and it influenced me in someway?

Comment: As you can see [here](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-4/) and [here](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-11/), 「(～は)(～に)手紙**を**読まれた。"(I) had (my) letter read (by someone)" (→ and it affected me; I was annoyed. So this can also be categorized as 迷惑の受身(suffering passive))」 and 「(～は)(～に)息子**を**褒められた。"(I) had (my) son praised (by someone)"」 can be categorized as 間接受身(indirect passive) or 持ち主の受身(possessor passive), and I think you can see the 代理**を**立てられた here as having the same construct.